# Customise person column with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Now the settings are made to be small:

[image]

Is there some way to make the person card bigger on height and font size?

I use Person or Group column.

Comment: You wan to make the image in list view bigger or the hover persona card?

Comment: Both picture and name look bigger while the functioning stay the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the profile picture of user in JSON using:

```
"elmType": "img",
"attributes": {
    "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
    "title": "@currentField.title"
}
...
```

You can use one of the below profile picture `size` in URL in above JSON.

**User Profile Picture sizes**:

```
Key     Size
S       48x48
M       72x72
L       300x?*
```

**References**:

1. [Display a person's profile picture in a circle](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-roundimage-format)
2. [Multi-Person Facepile](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-person-facepile)

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
                "width": "72px",
                "height": "72px",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "border-radius": "50%",
                "margin": "2px"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
                "title": "@currentField.title"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "vertical-align": "middle",
                "margin-left": "2px",
                "font-size": "20px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        }
    ],
    "defaultHoverField": "@currentField"
}
```

You can adjust the `width` & `height` for `img` element & `font-size` for `span` element as per your requirements.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This will take only the image, but I need  the button (picture AND the name) make bigger.

Comment: Try using JSON in updated answer.